# How do I isolate the text between 2 delimiters on the left and 7 delimiters on the right in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I have a string:

```
string = ""7807161604","Sat Jan 16 00:00:57 +0000 2010","Global focus begins tonight. Pretty interested to hear more about it.","Madison Alabama","al","17428434","81","51","Sun Nov 16 21:46:24 +0000 2008","243"
```

I only want the text: **"Global focus begins tonight. Pretty interested to hear more about it.""** which is between the 2nd and 3rd comma/delimiter. 
If i use:

```
i = string.split(',', 2)
s = i[2]
j = s.split(',',-7)
print j[0]
```

i will get the desired output. 
But, if there is an extra comma between the original string as shown below:

```
string = ""7807161604","Sat Jan 16 00:00:57 +0000 2010","Global focus begins tonight. Pretty interested, to hear more about it.","Madison Alabama","al","17428434","81","51","Sun Nov 16 21:46:24 +0000 2008","243""
```

Then this approach does not work because the output I require is being split. Can anyone please help and suggest a different approach or advise if I'm going wrong? thanks!

Comment: Is that a tuple or a single string?

Comment: I'm sorry that is a whole string, not a tuple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use python's built-in `csv` module to do this.

```
j = next(csv.reader([string]));
```

Now `j` is each item delimited by a `,` and will include commas if the value is wrapped in `"`.  See `j[2]`.